# writing __str__ method for Enum class python

Tags: python-3.x, enums

I have an enum class in python using list of strings:

```
from enum import Enum
myEnum = Enum('myEnum',['typeA',typeB','typeC'])
```

and I want to add method "**str**" to this enum class:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

so that when I use str() function, I only get the 'typeX' part, i.e. the enum part withou class name.
e.g.

```
print(str(myEnum.typeA)) # I want this to print "typeA" instead of "myEnum.typeA"
```

I do not know how to add the "**str**" method to this class as it is not class definition?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: we can subclass `Enum` and override `__str__` method

Comment: You can use assign a function to `myEnum.__str__ = whatever`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach which I feel is simpler and easier to customize. This is based on the [Allowed members and attributes of enumerations](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#allowed-members-and-attributes-of-enumerations), part of the official Enum documentation.

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class myEnum(Enum):
    typeA = auto()
    typeB = auto()
    typeC = auto()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is a usage example:

```
>>> print(myEnum.typeB)
typeB
```

Answer (score 8):

If this is something you do a lot, you can make your own base Enum class, and then use that in the function calls:

```
class MyBaseEnum(Enum):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

myEnum = MyBaseEnum('myEnum',['typeA','typeB','typeC'])
```

and in use:

```
>>> print(myEnum.typeB)
typeB
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for both the answers.
I used it as below and it worked:

```
from enum import Enum
myEnum = Enum('myEnum',['typeA','typeB','typeC'])
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
myEnum.__str__ = __str__

st = str(myEnum.typeA)
print(st)
```

it printed "typeA" instead of "myEnum.typeA" which is what I needed!